# Simple JS Question.(Changing Font for a string)

Tags: javascript

How do I change the font for `a.value = " ";`?

```
cleanTextarea(a) {
  a.value = "TEST",
  a.style.height = ""
}
```

Comment: sidenote, a space kind of does not have a font, and this should really be done in css as applying the font wouldn't look right switching between different ones and/or it's only going to be set once

Answer (score 1):

try  this

```
cleanTextarea(a) {
  a.style.fontFamily = "your favourite font",
  a.style.fontSize = "your custom font size",
  a.value = "TEST",
  a.style.height = ""
}
```

if that doesn't work, try adding !important. Example:

```
cleanTextarea(a) {
  a.style.fontFamily = "Arial !important",
  a.style.fontSize = "20px !important",
  a.value = "TEST",
  a.style.height = ""
}
```